# label arrow at midpoint in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikzcd I know of the 'description' qualifier which places the node with a white background on top of and in the middle of the arrow.  How can this best be achieved in tikz?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`midway` and `above`

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->](0,0)--(2,0) node[midway,above]{label}; %if you want to enforce a white background add fill=white to the node options
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second try:

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->](0,0)--(2,0) node[midway,fill=white]{label}; %for better vertical alignment you can add text height=.5em to the node options or a \strut inside the node text
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want the label to be on the arrow not above it.  e.g. ---label--->.

Comment: Ah great.  I actually tried that but I had 'auto' in tikzset which was the problem I think.

Comment: yup, it was auto that prevented it to work.